# javafx code to pick only the boundary of an arc on MOUSE_CLICKED event

Tags: java, javafx

I want to be able to click only the boundary of `Arc`s overlapping each other in a `StackPane`. Currently, my code below also picks the fill of the `Arc`s and I'm not able to fire the `MOUSE_CLICKED` event of the `arc1` when I click point p3 in the below depiction. The explanation of my desired outcome and current outcome is also below.

[image]

- When user clicks p1, code works as intended, prints "arc2"
- When user clicks p2, code prints "arc2" whereas the intended operation is to do nothing
- When user clicks p3, code prints "arc2" whereas the intended operation is to print "arc1"

This is because the fill area of the `Arc2` gets picked before `Arc1` even though the fill is transparent and `PickOnBounds` is set to `false`. I'm trying to find a way to not get the fill area to be picked. Failing that, I want to have the event handlers for both `Arc`s to be fired so I can handle the behavior myself.

Code representing my issue:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Example extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Arc arc1 = new Arc(100, 100, 100, 100, 90, 90);
        Arc arc2 = new Arc(0, 100, 100, 100, 0, 90);

        arc1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        arc2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        arc1.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        arc2.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        arc1.setStrokeWidth(10);
        arc2.setStrokeWidth(10);
        arc1.setType(ArcType.OPEN);
        arc2.setType(ArcType.OPEN);

        arc1.setPickOnBounds(false);
        arc2.setPickOnBounds(false);

        arc1.setOnMouseClicked(event -> System.out.println("arc1"));
        arc2.setOnMouseClicked(event -> System.out.println("arc2"));

      StackPane root = new StackPane();
      root.getChildren().add(arc1);
      root.getChildren().add(arc2);

      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

      primaryStage.setTitle("Picking Issues");
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

With [c0der's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3992939/c0der) help, I implemented my intended behavior as follows:

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
    import javafx.scene.Node;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
    import javafx.scene.shape.ArcType;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Example extends Application {

        private  Arc arc1, arc2;
        private StackPane root;

      @Override
      public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
          arc1 = getArc(200, 200, 200, 200, 90, 90, "arc1");
          arc2 = getArc(0, 200, 200, 200, 0, 90, "arc2");
          root = new StackPane(arc1, arc2);
          root.setOnMouseClicked(event -> onStackPaneClick(event.getX(), event.getY()));
          Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
          primaryStage.setScene(scene);
          primaryStage.show();
      }

      private Arc getArc(double x, double y,  double radiusX, double radiusY, double startAngle, double endAngle, String userData){    
          Arc arc = new Arc(x,y, radiusX,radiusY,startAngle, endAngle);
          arc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
          arc.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
          arc.setStrokeWidth(10);
          arc.setType(ArcType.OPEN);
          arc.setPickOnBounds(false);
          arc.setUserData(userData);
          return arc;
      }

      private void onStackPaneClick(double x, double y) {
        for (Node itNode : root.getChildren()) {
            if (itNode.contains(new Point2D(x, y))) {
                if (itNode instanceof Arc) {
                    Arc itArc = (Arc) itNode;
                    double centerDistance = Math.sqrt(
                            (x - itArc.getCenterX()) * (x - itArc.getCenterX()) +
                            (y - itArc.getCenterY()) * (y - itArc.getCenterY()));
                    if (centerDistance >= itArc.getRadiusX() - itArc.getStrokeWidth() / 2) {
                        System.out.println(itArc.getUserData());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          launch(args);
      }
    }
```

However, the question still remains technically unanswered as the initial question needs either;

- A way to exclude the "fill" area from click events, or,
- A way to have the event handlers of all shapes containing the clicked point to be fired when a clicked point is contained within more than one shape

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply check if [Node contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#contains-double-double-) the clicked point:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FxmlTest extends Application {

    private  Arc arc1, arc2;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        arc1 = getArc(100, 100, 100, 100, 90, 90);
        arc2 = getArc(0, 100, 100, 100, 0, 90);
        StackPane root = new StackPane(arc1, arc2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Arc getArc(double x, double y,  double radiusX, double radiusY, double startAngle, double endAngle){    
        Arc arc = new Arc(x,y, radiusX,radiusY,startAngle, endAngle);
        arc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        arc.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        arc.setStrokeWidth(10);
        arc.setType(ArcType.OPEN);
        arc.setPickOnBounds(false);
        arc.setOnMouseClicked(event -> checkClickedPoint(event.getX(), event.getY()));
        return arc;
    }
    private void checkClickedPoint(double x, double y) {
        Point2D clickedPoint = new Point2D(x, y);
        if(arc1.contains(clickedPoint)) {System.out.println("arc1");}
        if(arc2.contains(clickedPoint)) {System.out.println("arc2");}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(null);
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**
To avoid mouse click events from the fill area of the arc (the yellow area in the image)

[image]

you could construct a shape of the contour only, without the fill area.
Let's call the arc in the image `arc1`. 
Construct a second arc, `arc2` which is smaller and enclosed in `arc1`. 
`arc2` is constructed so it covers the yellow area. 
Subtracting `arc2` from `arc1` returns a shape which is the contour of `arc1`:

```
class ArcContour {

    private final Shape arcContour;
    private static final double STROKE = 10;

    public ArcContour(double x, double y, double radiusX, double radiusY, double startAngle, double length) {

        Arc arc1 = new Arc(x,y, radiusX,radiusY,startAngle, length);
        arc1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        arc1.setStrokeWidth(STROKE);
        arc1.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);
        arc1.setType(ArcType.OPEN);
        arc1.setPickOnBounds(false);

        Arc arc2 = new Arc(x,y, radiusX - STROKE,radiusY - STROKE,startAngle, length);
        arc2.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);
        arcContour = Shape.subtract(arc1, arc2);
    }

    Shape getShape() {
        return arcContour;
    }
}
```

Test it by:

```
public class FxmlTest extends Application {

    private  Shape shape;
    private static final double RADIUS = 100;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        shape = new ArcContour(150, 150, RADIUS, RADIUS, 30, 150).getShape();
        shape.setOnMouseClicked(event -> checkClickedPoint(event.getX(), event.getY()));
        StackPane root = new StackPane(shape);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    //this functinality can be refactored to ArcContour
    private void checkClickedPoint(double x, double y) {
        if( shape.contains(new Point2D(x, y))) {System.out.println("Arc clicked");}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this provides me a way to implement intended behavior although still prints "arc2" when I click p2. I will eliminate that by checking the distance from the `clickedPoint` to the `Arc`s center, but you might have a cleaner suggestion?

Comment: The reason is the p2 is within arc1. Set arc2 fill to non transparent to see.

Comment: I understand that but is there a way to determine whether the border or the fill is clicked or a way to ignore transparent areas for clicks?

Comment: The not-so-elegant way I can think of I adding another enclosed (smaller) transparent arc, and test the it does NOT contain the clicked point. My answer is partial so it may be better to up vote it rather than accepting it. You may also want to [edit] the question to clarify what is still unanswered or post a new one.

Comment: I didn't want to be picky but you are right, technically, the answer is still pending. I also edited with how I implemented my solution.

Comment: instead of editing the question with your solution, you might consider to post a self-answer - it would be more visible for future readers :)

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you. This enables each shape to have its own event handler and only registers clicks to the border.